# Deduce validation constraint through mapping

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.0 (not 2.1) and I wonder if is there a way to automatically deduce validation constraint through another relevant information, such as Doctrine mapping.

The specific thing that I want to do is to add to all properties mapped as `string` the validation constraint `MaxLength` with the `limit` parameter corresponding to the `length` parameter specified in Doctrine mapping.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I will extend the default assertion annotation mapping, and then inject the doctrine maping by DI. Chceck the mapping from doctrine if it's string add those two mentioned assertions.